# Rails ActionController::ParameterMissing error when creating new record in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ruby-on-rails-5, fastjsonapi

Rails 5.2 with fast_jsonapi 1.5, Ember 3.4

I create a new Tag record like this in Ember:

```
let newTag = this.get('store').createRecord('tag', {
  name: this.get('name')
});
newTag.save();
```

This sends the following json (as seen in the Network tab of Chrome as the Request Payload):

```
{"data":{"attributes":{"name":"photos","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},"type":"tags"}}
```

But Rails only gets (as verified by printing out the params in the create method of the TagsController):

```
{"controller"=>"tags", "action"=>"create"}
```

And it throws the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: tag)
```

And here is my controller code:

```
# app/controllers/tags_controller.rb
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    tag = Tag.create!(tag_params)
    render json: {status: "success"}
  end

  private

  def tag_params
    puts params
    params.require(:tag).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

What's the trick to get ember and rails to understand each other? Since ember is sending the "type" in the payload, can I get Rails to understand that this is the model and thus fulfill the requirement I've set that "tag" be present in the params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rereading the [action controller overview](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters) I learned I had to include  the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header in my request. I accomplished this by [customizing my application adapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_headers-customization) in Ember:

```
// app/adapters/application.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('headers', {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
  }
});
```

The next problem I had to deal with was changing my use of strong parameters in the Rails controller:

```
# app/controllers/tags_controller.rb

def tag_params
  params.require(:data).require(:attributes).permit(:name)
end
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

in ember 3.26 you can do like this :

```
export default class ApplicationAdapter extends JSONAPIAdapter {
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

instead of

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
init() {
this._super(...arguments);
this.set('headers', {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
```